# Django composing home pages or pages with several data sources

Tags: django, view

The site I am building includes a homepage composed of panels of summarised tabular data from applications within the Django project.

What is the recommended way of building these types of pages. In other MVC style frameworks this is usually handled by each application providing a summary view, each of these views is rendered into the panels to compose the page.

This makes a lot of sense as each sub view can then be cached individually, logic related to the particular summary is contained within the application and better follows the DRY mantra.

Is there general consensus on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) for each section, and assemble them in the appropriate template.